# Python LCD Display

Tags: python, loops, raspberry-pi

I was wondering how I can refresh/reload a code (loop) after it has been executed.
I used an LCD Display to show the CPU Temp and Daytime but it doesnt refresh automatically. Thanks

This is the code I want to reload:

```
lcd_byte(DISPLAY_LINE_1, DISPLAY_CMD)
lcd_string("CPU Temp: " + str(round(get_cpu_temp(), 2)))
lcd_byte(DISPLAY_LINE_2, DISPLAY_CMD)
lcd_string("Time:" + str(datetime.datetime.now().time()))
```

Comment: Sounds like an application for a loop. Please read a Python tutorial, it explains such things. BTW: The "D" in LCD stands for "display" already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple example, let's say you just want to repeat it once every 10 seconds. Note that this won't be perfectly "on the second", but will update the display once, and then continue to update it approximately every 10 seconds after:

```
import datetime
from time import sleep

while True:
    lcd_byte(DISPLAY_LINE_1, DISPLAY_CMD)
    lcd_string("CPU Temp: " + str(round(get_cpu_temp(), 2)))
    lcd_byte(DISPLAY_LINE_2, DISPLAY_CMD)
    lcd_string("Time:" + str(datetime.datetime.now().time()))

    sleep(10)
```

This loop will run forever, until you shut down the program.